# Using JNDI Connection pool as Datanucleus PersistenceManagerFactory

Tags: glassfish, jndi, datanucleus

I am developing a web application using DataNucleus as DAO layer (mainly due to historical reasons). It runs inside Payara server (a Glassfish 4 fork)
It works fine, but now I'd like to use a JNDI db connection pool to obtain the PersistenceManagerFactory for DataNucleus.
From the documentation, it seems that the following code would suffice:

```
pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory( "jdbc/HxWmDb", context );
```

but this way I obtain an error starting the application (DbSession is the class which implements the DAO layer, and the error line is exactly the one above):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:262)
at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:150)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1791)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1755)
at ejb.DbSession.<init>(DbSession.java:119)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40 cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:245)
```

Any suggestion?

Little update, as requested by DN1:

As a first approach, I tried exactly what is described in the link:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("datanucleus.ConnectionFactoryName","jdbc/HxWmDb");
PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties);
```

And the error is, as already said, that a URI is anyway required:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: You haven't specified persistence property 'datanucleus.ConnectionURL'
```

Comment: The "JNDI location" in JDOHelper is the JNDI location of a PMF, not some datastore! A "JNDI" datastore location is specified as a property for a PMF, maybe javax.jdo.option.ConnectionFactory ?

Comment: I have already tried the datasource approach (as for http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/datastore_connection.html#datasource), setting the property as below,  but DataNucleus complains that a uri is anyway required:

Comment: If you have tried something you should update your question with WHAT you have tried and the result. The fact remains that what you have tried in the question currently is wrong.

Comment: Regarding your update ... works for me when I do that. So perhaps there's more to your code than you post. Actually posting the FULL STACK TRACE would be a start point ... as would looking at the LOG in that specific case

Comment: The error implies that you are trying to remotely access the datasource hence the PortableRemoteObject.narrow. Do you have a jndi.properties or are you accessing the server remotely?